# how to set a title and gap between paragraphs?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I want to rewrite an existing view to look like this:

[image]

This is my current xml and screenshot:

[image]

I'm using this 9 patch:

[image]

```
<!--
    ========================================================================
    * Information layout - contains the explanation text on the background 
    ========================================================================
-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_info1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/widget_nodata_title"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/widget_error" 
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_error"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_text_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_info1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/widget_nodata_info1"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_info2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/widget_nodata_info2"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_info3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/widget_nodata_info3"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--
    ========================================================================
    * Buttons layout - contains all the texts 
    ========================================================================
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_text_info"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_btn_enter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/widget_no_data_accept"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_btn_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/widget_no_data_close"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout> <!--  -->
```

How pose the title on top the gray top area?

How to center the two bottom buttons?

Comment: I'm guessing they're using `alignParentTop`, `alignParentLeft` and for the second (gapped) paragraph - `alignParentBottom`. The button is just `justified`

Comment: @Shark tried. It didn't work. can you please view my xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your button layout to the bottom and center them as you want. If you can be more clear I can help you about the house image and title as well. (about the id names).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_btn_enter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/widget_no_data_accept"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_btn_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/widget_no_data_close"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If this is your imageview for the house picture, then it is fixed as well. Just give top margin as much as your want.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_error"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/widget_error" />
```

Comment: gravity didn't work for me. I have edited my xml. can you please view?

Comment: would it be better to use one big linear layout instead of relative one?

Comment: did you exactly copy-pasted this and check because it is working for me? I wrote here after testing it myself. It is not just centering the gravity but also giving fill parent to the outer linearlayout. Please try the imageview too for it is working as well. And yes, it would be better using a linearlayout since you don't have a complicated interface but it is up to your coding style.

Comment: didn't work for the bottom buttons. also my title disappeared (hidden behind the gray area)

Comment: @EladBenda which emulator/device are you using, and which version (AOSP or ?) of Android are you running on it, and which SDK are you building your app against? What API level are you targeting?